# What is the right sequence to write a right sql-Alchemy Query?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to Update My database through excel file, but I find this error when I am running the application, I think the problem in the Syntax of the query, I am not sure what is the right syntax for sqlAlchemy Query as I didn't find reference for that...

Here's the error looks like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Tooling/20200206/MyDB_Update.py", line 21, in <module>
    if(Add_To_DB.remove_duplicates(item,myCursor, myDB)):
  File "D:\Tooling\20200206\MyDB.py", line 22, in remove_duplicates
    mycursor.execute(sql, value)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ','. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

Process finished with exit code 1
```

and here's My SQL Connection `.py`

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


class Add_To_DB():
    # connect db
    mydb = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://WWX542337CDCD\SMARTRNO_EXPRESS/myDB?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')
    mycursor = mydb.raw_connection().cursor()

    def remove_duplicates(comp_zip, mycursor, mydb):
        # fetching the column from database

        flag = False
        sql = "SELECT GBSC,SiteName,CellCI,CellLAC,CellName,CellIndex FROM [myDB].[dbo].[mnm_rotterdam_5_daily_details-20191216081027] WHERE (GBSC=? and SiteName=?, CellCI =? ,CellLAC=?,CellName=?,CellIndex=?); "
        GBSC = comp_zip[0]
        Site_Name = comp_zip[1],
        Cell_CI = comp_zip[2],
        cell_LAC = comp_zip[3]
        cell_name = comp_zip[4],
        cell_index = comp_zip[5],

        value = (GBSC, Site_Name, Cell_CI, cell_LAC, cell_name, cell_index)
        mycursor.execute(sql, value)
        myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

        if (myresult):
            # print("title URL already exists")
            flag = True
            return (flag)
        else:
            # print("title URL dosen't exist")
            return (flag)

    def insert_into_db(insert_zip, mycursor, mydb):
        sql = "Insert into [myDB].[dbo].[mnm_rotterdam_5_daily_details-20191216081027] (GBSC,SiteName,CellCI,CellLAC,CellName,CellIndex) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)"
        GBSC = insert_zip[0]
        Site_Name = insert_zip[1],
        Cell_CI = insert_zip[2],
        cell_LAC = insert_zip[3]
        cell_name = insert_zip[4],
        cell_index = insert_zip[5],

        value = (GBSC, Site_Name, Cell_CI, cell_LAC, cell_name, cell_index)
        mycursor.execute(sql, value)
        return 'Added'
```

and this is my Update function code `.py`

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
from DB import Add_To_DB
mydb = create_engine(
    'mssql+pyodbc://WWX542337CDCD\SMARTRNO_EXPRESS/myDB?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')  # name of database
mycursor = mydb.raw_connection().cursor()
myDB = Add_To_DB.mydb
myCursor = Add_To_DB.mycursor
df = pd.read_excel('MNM_Rotterdam_5_Daily_Details-20191216081027.xlsx',sheet_name='GSM Details')
print(df)
date=df['Date']
GBSC=df['GBSC']
Site_Name=df['Site Name']
Cell_CI=df['Cell CI']
cell_LAC=df['Cell LAC']
cell_name=df['Cell Name']
cell_index=df['CellIndex']

comp_zip=zip(GBSC,Site_Name,Cell_CI,cell_LAC,cell_name,cell_index)
for item in comp_zip:
    if(Add_To_DB.remove_duplicates(item,myCursor, myDB)):
        continue#if data already then flag is true and not insert into db
    Add_To_DB.insert_into_db(item,myCursor, myDB)
#     ##write insert function here
```

and this is my Insert query:

```
sql = "Insert into [myDB].[dbo].[mnm_rotterdam_5_daily_details-20191216081027] (GBSC,SiteName,CellCI,CellLAC,CellName,CellIndex) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)"
```

and this is my Select query

```
        sql = "SELECT GBSC,SiteName,CellCI,CellLAC,CellName,CellIndex FROM [myDB].[dbo].[mnm_rotterdam_5_daily_details-20191216081027] WHERE (GBSC=? and SiteName=?, CellCI =? ,CellLAC=?,CellName=?,CellIndex=?); "
```

and this is my DB query Looks like:

```
SELECT *
      ,[Date]
      ,[GBSC]
      ,[BSCIndex]
      ,[SiteName]
      ,[CellCI]
      ,[CellLAC]
      ,[CellName]
      ,[CellIndex]
      ,[SiteName.1]
      ,[Voice_SetupFailRate_2G]
      ,[Voice_DropRate_2G]
      ,[OutgHandover_SuccesRate_2G]
      ,[Packet_SetupFailRate_2G]
      ,[Voice_ErlHr_2G]
      ,[Voice_ErlHr_2G_Daily]
      ,[Packet_DLMBytes_2G]
      ,[Packet_ULMBytes_2G]
      ,[Availability_2G]
      ,[Availability_2G_Cluster]
      ,[K3001:FailedSDCCHSeizuresduetoBusySDCCH]
      ,[K3000:SDCCHSeizureRequests]
      ,[CM30:CallDropsonSDCCH]
      ,[CA3030J:CallSetupIndications(SDCCH)(CircuitService)]
      ,[CA313:SuccessfulAssignments]
      ,[CA310:AssignmentRequests]
      ,[CM33:CallDropsonTrafficChannel]
      ,[CM3302:CallDropsonTrafficChannelinStableState(ReleaseIndication)]
      ,[A03701:NormalSpeechDisconnections]
      ,[A9103:NumberofFailedDownlinkGPRSTBFEstablishmentsduetoNoChannel]
      ,[A9303:NumberofFailedDownlinkEGPRSTBFEstablishmentsduetoNoChannel]
      ,[A9104:NumberofFailedDownlinkGPRSTBFEstablishmentsduetoMSNoResponse]
      ,[A9304:NumberofFailedDownlinkEGPRSTBFEstablishmentsduetoMSNoResponse]
      ,[A9101:NumberofDownlinkGPRSTBFEstablishmentAttempts]
      ,[A9301:NumberofDownlinkEGPRSTBFEstablishmentAttempts]
      ,[CH313:NumberofSuccessfulOutgoingInternalInter-CellHandovers]
      ,[CH333:SuccessfulOutgoingExternalInter-CellHandovers]
      ,[CH311:NumberofOutgoingInternalInter-CellHandoverCommands]
      ,[CH331:OutgoingExternalInter-CellHandoverCommands]
      ,[K3014:TrafficVolumeonTCH(Erl)]
      ,[TR373:CellAvailability(%)]
      ,[K3011A:FailedTCHSeizuresduetoBusyTCH(TrafficChannel)]
      ,[K3011B:FailedTCHSeizuresinTCHHandoversduetoBusyTCH(TrafficChannel)]
      ,[K3034:TCHHTrafficVolume(Erl)]
      ,[K3004:TrafficVolumeonSDCCH(Erl)]
      ,[AR9311:AverageNumberofOccupiedPDCHs]
      ,[K3010A:TCHSeizureRequests(TrafficChannel)]
      ,[CM30C:CallDropsonSDCCH(CallType)]
      ,[ZTR104B:CallDropRateonSDCCH(CallType)(%)]
      ,[K3003A:SuccessfulSDCCHSeizures(CallType)]
      ,[K3005:AvailableSDCCHs]
      ,[K3006:ConfiguredSDCCHs]
      ,[K3016:ConfiguredTCHs]
      ,[K3015:AvailableTCHs]
      ,[TCHTrafficVolumeperChannel(Erl)]
      ,[M3030A:CallDropsonTCH(TA)]
      ,[M3030B:CallDropsonTCH(UplinkReceivedLevel)]
      ,[M3030C:CallDropsonTCH(DownlinkReceivedLevel)]
      ,[M3030D:CallDropsonTCH(UplinkandDownlinkReceivedLevel)]
      ,[M3030E:CallDropsonTCH(UplinkFER)]
      ,[M3030F:CallDropsonTCH(DownlinkFER)]
      ,[M3030G:CallDropsonTCH(UplinkandDownlinkFER)]
      ,[M3030H:CallDropsonTCH(UplinkQuality)]
      ,[M3030I:CallDropsonTCH(DownlinkQuality)]
      ,[M3030J:CallDropsonTCH(UplinkandDownlinkQuality)]
      ,[M3030K:CallDropsonTCH(Other)]
      ,[CM331:CallDropsonRadioInterfaceinHandoverState(TrafficChannel)]
      ,[CM332:CallDropsDuetoNoMRfromMSforaLongTime(TrafficChannel)]
      ,[CM333:CallDropsduetoAbisTerrestrialLinkFailure(TrafficChannel)]
      ,[CM334:CallDropsduetoEquipmentFailure(TrafficChannel)]
      ,[CM335:CallDropsduetoForcedHandover(TrafficChannel)]
      ,[CM337:CallDropsafterAnswer]
      ,[CM338:SuccessfulConnections]
      ,[CM339:ClearRequestsSentontheAinterface(TCH)(TrafficChannel)]
      ,[M3020A:CallDropsonSDCCH(TA)]
      ,[M3020B:CallDropsonSDCCH(ReceivedLevel)]
      ,[M3020C:CallDropsonSDCCH(Quality)]
      ,[M3020D:CallDropsonSDCCH(Other)]
  FROM [myDB].[dbo].[mnm_rotterdam_5_daily_details-20191216081027]
```

Any One have any Idea about this error?

Comment: In `Site_Name = comp_zip[1],` etc. you've assigned a 1-tuple to `Site_Name`. Remove the trailing commas.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä Thanks A lot it solve, but I found another error with the syntax :)

`pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ','. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")`

Comment: `WHERE (GBSC=? and SiteName=?, CellCI =? ,CellLAC=?,CellName=?,CellIndex=?)` does seem a bit odd. The brackets seem unnecessary, and instead of commas perhaps you meant `AND` or `OR`? Maybe something like `WHERE GBSC = ? AND (SiteName = ? OR CellCI = ? OR CellLAC = ? OR CellName = ? OR CellIndex = ?)` (just trying to make a guess at the original intent)

Comment: @Ilja Everilä Thanks a lot it solved... but there's another problem when I check if it update the database I see it didn't any updates in the sql... Do you have any Idea how to create a funtion that's prints the output to make sure the function works good or not? :)